# I have two dropdowns in my angular js Page, If i will select superuser from one dropdown then another dropdown should be disabled

Tags: angularjs

I have two dropdowns in my angular js Page, If i will select superuser from one dropdown then another dropdown should be disabled,but again if i will change the value from superuser to something else in another dropdown then it will be enabled again.How can i do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, but all rely on using the `ng-disabled` directive on the second dropdown.

You *could* use a method to determine if the select should be closed, but I feel those sorts of methods fire too much. It's clearer to give each user a boolean to describe if they are a "super user" or not.

Once you select the user (binding the user to the scope using `ng-model`), you can then pass `ng-disabled` the selected users "super user" boolean to disable it or not.

Check out this plunker, using `ctrl as ...` syntax. http://plnkr.co/edit/QQOxnPj1Mn9McgDSMInB?p=preview